# Switching between two spans in a div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, hover

What i try to achieve is as follows:

I have a div with inserted two span's. `span A` and `span B`. By default I want span A to be visible and span B to be invisible. When you hover over the div I want span A to be replaced by span B. See the following: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IK12768pk43Z5FvXezLp?p=preview)

```
<div class="answer">
    <span class="a">20<span>
    <span class="b">80%</span>
</div>
```

```js
$(".answer").hover(function(){
    $(".b").toggleClass(".visible");
});
```

Comment: Why do you need jQuery for that, should be easy with just CSS

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/roVdfancAMK82bsGrBYM?p=preview

Comment: Please always include your code in the question.

Comment: Your closing tag for the first span needs to be fixed

Comment: see @rdubya's comment - http://plnkr.co/edit/4u85Vi7aRHbEPVIEO19P?p=preview - I just closed that `<span>` in results.html line 5 and 9!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use jquery toggle:

```
$(".answer").on('mouseenter mouseleave',function(){

            $('.b').toggle();
            $('.a').toggle();
 });
```

Link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hhalse/1fsezkrv/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".answer").on('mouseenter',function(){
         console.log("enter")
                $('.b').show();
                $('.a').hide();
     });

    $(".answer").on('mouseleave',function(){
         console.log("leave")
                $('.a').show();
                $('.b').hide();
     });
```

**[JS FILLDE demo](http://jsfiddle.net/byaqd8n4/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hover()` provided by jQuery(even though only css is sufficient):

```
$('#yourTag').on('hover', function(){
    $('#yourSpan1').hide();
    $('#yourSpan2').show();
    },
    function(){
    $('#yourSpan1').show();
    $('#yourSpan2').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply hiding/showing. This will get you what you want based on your example.

```
<style>
    .answer:hover .a { display: none; }
    .answer:hover .b { display: inline; }
</style>
```